# Type 'Promise<number>' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: typescript, promise

I'm trying to return number from a promise: the function `getActualId` call from `chrome.local.storage` and returns a promise:

```
function getActualId(){
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        chrome.storage.sync.get({
            userId: true
        }, function (userId) {
            resolve(userId.userId);
        });
    });
}
```

this function gets the right value but when I call it from another function I keep getting the the `getId` function return a `Promise<number>` and not a promise.

```
async function getId(){
    let id:number = 0;
    await getActualId().then( function(userid:number){
        id =  userid;
    })
    return id
}
```

How can I get the real value of `id` from `getId` and not a `promise<number>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You almost never use `then` in an `async` function.¹ The point of `async` functions is you can use `await` instead. In your case, you want to assign the result of `await getActualId()` to `id`:

```
async function getId(){
    let id:number = await getActualId();
    return id;
}
```

(Although it's not clear why that function would need to exist, it's just a wrapper around `getActualId`.)

There's a problem with `getActualId`, though, and if we fix that we don't need a type annotation on `id` in `getId`: `getActualId` is missing its return type annotation, so it implicitly returns `Promise<any>`. If it's returning `Promise<number>`, you need to say that:

```
function getActualId(): Promise<number> {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        chrome.storage.sync.get({
            userId: true
        }, function (userId) {
            resolve(userId.userId);
        });
    });
}
```

[Example in the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20getActualId()%3A%20Promise%3Cnumber%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Promise((resolve)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(Math.floor(Math.random()%20*%20100))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20100)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0Aasync%20function%20getId()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20id%20%3D%20await%20getActualId()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20id%3B%0A%7D):

```
function getActualId(): Promise<number> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
        }, 100);
    });
}
async function getId() {
    let id = await getActualId();
    return id;
}
```

If you hover `id` in `getId`, you'll see that TypeScript knows it's a `number` thanks to the signature of `getActualId`, so we don't need the type annotation as TypeScript can infer it.

---

¹ By "almost never" I mean genuinely almost never. The only example I can think of is if you have a bunch of operations to do in parallel (so you're using `Promise.all`) and you need to do a transform on the result of one of them. Then you *might* do this:

```
const [first, second, third] = await Promise.all([
   firstOp(),
   secondOp().then(value => value.toUpperCase()),
   thirdOp()
]);
```

since using `await` on `secondOp` would delay the start of `thirdOp` (while the above doesn't).

Comment: @j.her - TypeScript understands `await` unwraps promises.

Comment: @j.her - Just realized there's a problem with `getActualId`, though. Updated the answer to address it.

Comment: an interesting answer. I'd like to add a little thing. async functions are considered as promises so what `getId` used to return is actually the promise of the `getId` function not the first promise. so we could just get it like this `getId().then(console.log)` if we want to just print it afterwards.